# Spark in standalone mode do not take more than 2 executors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have set up spark in standalone mode.
I run spark-submit as:

->spark-submit --master spark://127.0.0.1:7077 --driver-memory 600M --executor-memory 500M --num-executors 3 spark_dataframe_example.py

Here I have set number of executors as 3 and executor memory as 500M and driver memory as 600M.
But in history server web UI, I can see only 2 executors.
I have attached screenshots

[image]

In above screenshots, I could see two executors and one has executor id "driver" with memory 168M and another has  executor id "0" with memory 110M.
So my question is, Why it created 2 executors instead of 3.And how the memory is distributed among this 2 executors even though I have specified executor memory as 500M.
And sum of memory of both executor (168+110=278) is not equal to 500M.

Comment: The screenshot is illegible. `--num-executors` only affects job submitted to YARN and Kubernetis deployments and not to the standalone ones. You can set `spark.executor.cores` to prevent the executors from using all the available cores and thus have more than one executor per worker node.

Comment: HI Hristo,thanks for reply.I have edited the screenshot. can u xplain why I have 2 executors in standalone mode(is it default?). And how the memory is distributed in both this executors?How 110M and 168M memory  is assigned for these executors even though i have specified executor memory to be 500M.I am new to spark.Appreciate ur response

Comment: Can you show your cluster configuration? How many nodes there are?

Comment: I have set up spark in standalone mode in a single machine. One master and one slave process.

Comment: With one master and one worker processes, by default Spark will launch two executors, each of which will take over all CPU cores on the respective node. Limiting that number by setting 'spark.executor.cores' will enable more executors to be launched.

Comment: Hi Hristo, can u pls help to know how the storage memory of 110MB and 168MB is calculated for both executors?

Comment: Spark memory management is quite convoluted. You can read more about it in the official documentation or [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-Memory-Management/ta-p/317794).